# Can I make apache look for url encodings as literal filenames using mod-rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am dealing with an older website that unfortunately has images saved sometimes as

`kitty%2Bcat.jpg`   (literally with %2B in there)

but sometimes as

`kitty+cat.jpg`

(one or the other, not both will exist)

Unfortunately when a browser makes a request for kitty%2Bcat.jpg it never tries to find the literal filename with that - if kitty+cat.jpg exists, it will serve it, if not, it 404s

Can I use some mod-rewrite rules so that if kitty%2Bcat.jpg is requested but kitty+cat.jpg does not exist and kitty%2Bcat.jpg does, kitty%2Bcat.jpg is served?

I am imaging some of the logic involved but still missing some pieces.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \%2B
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]
```

See - how do I force apache to serve it literally and not 404 ?

Perhaps apache actually sees it as  kitty+cat and never gets a chance to examine it as %2B, so I have to do something else like this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ $1\%2B$2 [L]
```

But unfortunately that is not robust enough as there may be multiple %2B and other encodings.

Comment: Is it possible to rename all the files that contain %2B to + ?

Comment: Thinking about it some more, technically shouldn't those files be request as kitty%252Bcat.jpg ... the % should be urlencoded

Answer (score 1):

Try the [NE] No-Escape flag http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

so

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NE]`

Shot in the dark, seems that it might work

Comment: Oh wow, I completely missed that one! I wonder if I can use NE on the final RewriteRule too, hmm.

Comment: Unfortunately after some fiddling, I believe NE was meant for the final rewrite rule to pass a url unescaped and has no effect on examining the original url before it was decoded